# Which Azure Active Directory Graph API should I use?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I recently figured out that there are *two* Graph APIs availble for Azure Active Directory. There is the unified `graph.microsoft.com` and the AAD specific `graph.windows.net`:

> Azure AD Graph API functionality is also available through Microsoft
>   Graph, a unified API that also includes APIs from other Microsoft
>   services like Outlook, OneDrive, OneNote, Planner, and Office Graph,
>   all accessed through a single endpoint with a single access token.

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-permission-scopes)

Is there any reason to use the unifed Graph API when I only need to browse AAD objects? Will the AAD specific `graph.windows.net` GraphAPI get deprecated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has been no announcement of Azure AD Graph API's deprecation and we (and others) use it in production every day.

If you can get what you want through Azure AD Graph API, I'd say use it. If you need something else from the Microsoft Graph API (like emails or contacts), use that one.

Comment: Thanks juunas. Good to know.

Comment: Maybe you can answer me another question. I am able to register an AAD application and if I grant the application permission to Graph API and Windows Azure Active Directory I can authentiacate using the Client-ID and Client-Secret and perform requests using the AAD Graph API. However, If I go back to the classic portal and remove all permissions, I am still able to perform requests to the Graph API. Any idea?

Comment: If your client uses an existing token that was created before your changes, that token will contain the permission to access the API. Wait an hour for the token to expire.